# "Publish at" in Umbraco doesn't work (401 error)

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, publishing, unauthorized

The publish at functionality doesn't work- the items simply stay unpublished forever.

There are two errors in the log that are somehow connected - both are 401 errors.

I tried to enable anonymous authentication to the folder Umbraco/Webservices, but that didn't help. I couldn't find any solution after hours of reading.

```
Error in ping. The base URL used in the request was: ***, see http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/umbracoSettings/#ScheduledTasks documentation for details on setting a baseUrl if this is in error
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.KeepAlive.Start(ApplicationContext appContext, IUmbracoSettingsSection settings)
```

-

```
An error occurred with the scheduled publishing. The base url used in the request was: ***, see http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/umbracoSettings/#ScheduledTasks documentation for details on setting a baseUrl if this is in error
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing.PerformRun()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `/Config/umbracoSettings.config` in scheduledTask node set the base url to the path of your website /umbraco/, like this:

```
<scheduledTasks baseUrl="www.yoursite.com/umbraco/">
    <!-- add tasks that should be called with an interval (seconds) -->
    <!--    <task log="true" alias="test60" interval="60" url="http://localhost/umbraco/test.aspx"/>-->
  </scheduledTasks>
```

From the umbraco [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/)

`baseUrl`: (v6.2.5 & v7.1.9+) This is optional and should only be used if the base URL cannot be detected. This might occur if your hosting setup has some special proxies setup. See this issue for more details: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5391

Comment: This setting is obsolete as of 7.2.7, use umbracoApplicationUrl instead